# Low-Level Graphics in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, app-store

I am new to Swift so am not familiar with any of the library structures and whatnot. I am wondering though if there is a way to perform low-level graphics manipulations, such as building rectangles and paths from scratch (similar to the canvas in HTML5), so that you don't have to use the built-in components in UIKit or Foundation or whatnot.

That is, I am wondering if it is possible to build your own UI framework on top of simpler primitives (like the rectangle and path in the HTML5 canvas), also taking into account touch events and keyboard events and whatnot. Wondering where to look for more information on how to do that.

Also wondering if an app built this way would be acceptable as an app in the app store (that is, it wouldn't get rejected for using its own low-level graphics abstraction rather than using i.e. UIKit or Foundation).

Comment: Maybe look towards [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics)

Comment: Depending on how low-level you want to go, `UIBezierPath` might be enough. Or you could try Metal.

Comment: Create a `UIView` subclass called Rectangle and override `drawRect` method and use `UIBezierPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `QuartzCore`: 1) create UIView subclass and override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`;   2) subclass `CALayer` and override `-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`, add this layer to the target UIView object.

Because it's also based on `UIView`, so you don't need to do extra work to handle user touches or any other interface events.

2. Lower level: Using OpenGL ES to create graphic object and building touch dispatch system by yourself. Just likes mobile game engine.